# How to find which revision of a file a line of code was moved?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I'm using VisualSVN Server and TortoiseSVN, and I'm trying to find where a specific line appears, across multiple revisions of a specific file.

I'm trying to see where, in past revisions, `save(12);` appears, and in which revisions it's moved, compared to my working copy.

A unified diff between r1 and my working copy only shows the initial location. I've tried viewing the diffs individually, but there are hundreds of revisions.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the TortoiseSVN blame tool on the current revision of the file you should see the revision that that line became what it is now, (and who did it).

Comment: You miss requirement of historical aspect - thus blame must be performed in cycle, using revision of string-in-question as new source revision

Comment: If the last change to that line was the move it will show as the blame  tool shows last rev who line format.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for that, but it doesn't quite show me what I'm after. It only shows the line once, in it's current state, as of the the latest revision. I think @LazyBadger got it right.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done manually, or automatically using a script, and works in stages but you will be amazed how fast:

1. Write a grep command that passes if the line is in the one position fails in the other - e.g. **grep -n** "*Text of the line*" *filename.ext* **| grep** *CurrentLineNo***:**
2. Assuming that you have 1000 possible revisions this should pass at 1000 fail at 0
3. Update the one file to rev 500 and run it again - if it passes you go down fails you go up in either case you use us a difference of half the previous, and keep doing the same i.e. 250, 125, 62, 31, 15, 7, 4, 2, 1 - at the end of this process - (a binary search) - you will have two adjacent revisions of the file 1 passing 1 failing - in just ten steps for 1000 revisions 20 for a million.

Comment: BTW Distributed VCS's such as git and mercurial have the option to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Preface**

- "First appearing of string" in terms of diff is first appearing of "+ string" in diff output
- "in which revisions it's moved" in terms of diff (in assumption, that new line is out of diff-context /3 lines around as default/ for old line) is appearing "- string" and "+ string" in the same diff

**Not ready-to-use code, but dirty draft ideas**

*Pure Subversion way*

This way have (at least) two methods: exploring history from top to bottom with blame and from bottom to top with log+diff

Blame-method 1) `svn blame FILE > BLAMED-FILE`, 2) find in BLAMED-FILE string "save(12)", note string-number (any way) and revision-of-last-change (first column) REV 3) move back in history `svn blame -r REV FILE > BLAMED-FILE`

Repeat steps 2-3, while a) changing string-number of "save(12)" will not show "Movement revision" (it's previous in line, than current) b) REV in file will be equal to current - it's revision of appearing "save(12)"

Log+diff-method 1) `svn log -q -v FILE` (get list of revisions, which affect in any form FILE) 2) for every revision in list perform `svn diff -c REV | grep save(12) > FILE-REV` in from oldest to newest revisions direction 3) Find revisions, which correlate to second note in preface, checking FILE-REV

*Mercurial+hgsubversion way*

Tested on local materials. I want to see history of line "Region=-MA" in file

```
>hg grep --all -n Region Charter.ini
Charter.ini:599:28:+:Region=-NE
Charter.ini:598:23:-:Region=
Charter.ini:598:26:-:Region=-MA
Charter.ini:598:24:+:Region=-MA
Charter.ini:597:13:+:Region=-MI
Charter.ini:597:16:+:Region=-GA
Charter.ini:597:19:+:Region=-CA
Charter.ini:597:23:+:Region=
Charter.ini:597:26:+:Region=-MA
```

One command with answer "`Region=-MA` string appeared in revision 597 (SVN number is 598, +1) in string 26. In revision 598 string was moved to string 24", and diffs confirm it.

597 (file added)

```
>hg diff -c 597 Charter.ini
diff -r 7e3dfc891358 -r 25efa70e5350 Charter.ini
--- /dev/null   Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970 +0000
+++ b/Charter.ini       Tue Dec 29 08:27:48 2009 +0000
...
+Region=-MA
+75.130.96.0-75.130.111.255
```

598

```
>hg diff -c 598 Charter.ini
diff -r 25efa70e5350 -r 5665435f74b4 Charter.ini
--- a/Charter.ini       Tue Dec 29 08:27:48 2009 +0000
+++ b/Charter.ini       Tue Dec 29 13:09:58 2009 +0000
...
-//CHARTER-NET-5BLK
 66.188.0.0-66.191.255.255
+71.80.0.0-71.95.255.255
+75.128.0.0-75.143.255.255   
...
-
-//NETBLK-CHARTER-NET
-Region=
-75.128.0.0-75.143.255.255
+71.84.32.0-71.84.63.255

 Region=-MA
 75.130.96.0-75.130.111.255
```

Why I used substring instead of full-string? Just because in case of full string I got strange and unexpected result (compare to previous grep)

```
>hg grep --all -n Region=-MA Charter.ini
Charter.ini:597:26:+:Region=-MA
```